# didFinishDownloadingToURL is downloaded file securely stored?

Tags: ios, security, nsurlsession

When I use NSURLSession to download file in background mode with downloadTaskWithRequest the file is downloaded to "cache" location first and in didFinishDownloadingToURL I should move it to another location.

Is this cache location secure? Is there any risk or exposing confidential data? If so is there better way how to securely download files in background mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On iOS, no apps other than the OS itself can touch files in your app's sandbox directory, so it is relatively secure.  If the device is jailbroken, obviously all bets are off.

In OS X, it is probably not nearly that secure.  :-)

Comment: So if the device get stolen or pluged to hostile (but trusted ) pc can they get acces to the file?

Comment: If a machine is trusted, it can potentially access any file stored anywhere on the device, which means there's no such thing as a secure location.

Comment: So can i keep this file only in memory? Or can it be excripted before its put to this cache location?

Comment: You can use a data task, but not in the background.  A better solution, if that level of security is truly essential, would be to have your server encrypt the data before sending it, using a key that is known only to your app (and ideally, known only to a single copy of your app running on a single device that has registered itself as belonging to that account) and then decrypt the data in your app.